# open angular modal from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a modal service to handle the opening and closing of popups. From a controller I simple inject the dependency and do the following:

```
function LoginRegisterController($scope, login, register) {
  $scope.openLogin = login.activate;
  ...
  $scope.closeLogin = login.deactivate;
}
```

The thing is when the user is not logged he should be prompted to login. And for this I need to open the modal from a directive and not a controller. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
angular.module('mgApp.directives').directive('promptLogin', [ 'login', function(login) {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('$load', function () {
        login.activate;
    })
  };

  return {
    link: link
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Why not pass into the directive whether or not the person is logged in?  Or use an `ng-if` in your html to show a different directive based on login?

Comment: No problem.  If you need any help with it, just let me know.  Also, if this answer does help, could you upvote it or mark it as answer?  Trying to get some reputation.  :)